# Can't create SharePoint 2013 project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: 2013

I have a strange problem, I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on SharePoint 2016, I cant create SharePoint 2013 projects. I can create 2016 projects. I'm getting an error like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think it is strange. It just says that SharePoint 2013 is not installed on the box, which is true. Also it is not related to version of Visual Studio.

Why to create SharePoint 2013 solution in the first place? If you need to create backward compatible solution you have to create it on server with proper version of SharePoint, in your case SharePoint Server 2013 or SharePoint Foundation 2013.